# Format date and ignore records with special characters using perl

Tags: perl

I have a input file with 3 fields as shown.  I want to group the server based on application.  I am not interested in any application with any of these characters (curly braces, space, dot).  The date should be converted into dd-mmm-yyyy  (18-MAY-2013)format.

with help, I have partially achieved the form of output I want but failing on formatting date.

I would appreciate any help in formatting date and also eliminating records with special characters in application from my output.

Input:

```
Date                 Server        application
01/02/2013 00:00     abc123        perl_module_1
01/02/2013 00:00     abc123        oracle_patch_201
03/05/2014 00:00     abc123        Microsoft()_pa.1.tch_71 (2)
04/04/2015 00:00     xyz1          oracle_patch_201
02/12/2015 00:00     xyz1          Cygwin_app
03/11/2013 00:00     lpr567        perl_module_1
```

Output:

```
ABL "TEST:perl_module_1" /UPDATE=(server[("abc123","lpr567"),("01-FEB-2013 00:00","03-NOV-2013 00:00")])
ABL "TEST:oracle_patch_201" /UPDATE=(server[("abc123","xyz1"),("03-MAY-2014 00:00","04-APR-2015 00:00")])
ABL "TEST:Cygwin_app" /UPDATE=(server[("xyz1"),("02-DEC-2015 00:00")])
```

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'input.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "could not open $file: $!";
open(my $fh, '>', 'output.cmd');
my $application_string;
my $date_string;
my $oracledate;
my %applications_on;
my %servers_on;
my %date_on;

while ( <$info> ) {
   chomp;
   my ( $date, $time, $server, $application ) = split; 
   my %month_name;
   @month_name{ 0 .. 11 } = qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct Nov Dec);
   my ( $day, $month, $year ) = split ('/', $date);
   $date = join " ", $day, $month_name{$month}, $year;
  # my @date_values = split ('/',$date);
  # my $date_values[1] =~ s/01/JAN/;
  # $date = ($date_values[0].'-'.$date_values[1].'-'.$date_values[2]);
   push ( @{ $servers_on{$application} }, '"'.$server.'"');
   push ( @{ $date_on{$application} }, '"'.$date.'"');
}

foreach my $application ( keys %servers_on, keys %date_on ) {
    my $server_string = join ( ",", @{ $servers_on{$application} } ) ; 
    my $date_string = join ( ",", @{ $date_on{$application} } );
    printf $fh "ABL \"TEST:$application\" /UPDATE=(server[($server_string),($date_string)])\n";
}
close $info;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Skipping records with special characters:**

This really depends on your definition of "special characters."

```
while ( <$info> ) {
    chomp;
    next if /[ whatever characters you think are special ]/;
```

or possibly better:

```
    next unless /^[ -~]+$/;
```

That should skip the line unless it only contains low-ascii printable characters.

**Converting the date:**

```
use Time::Piece
  ...
my $new_date = uc Time::Piece
                  ->strptime($date, '%m/%d/%Y')
                  ->strftime('%d-%b-%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the date. Use [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) to help you translate and format the date. Using standard Perl modules will make your work much easier.

How is your file set? Are these tab separated fields? If so, you should use [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) to help you parse the text file. Since I don't know the actual format, I'll cheat.

---

This shows you how to use `Time::Piece` to read in and format your date. It also shows you how I use Perl regular expressions to throw out the first line and any application with *special characters*. The `/\W/` represents any character that's not alphabetic, numeric, or an underscore.

I split your line into four pieces of data on one or more spaces. `Time::Piece->strptime` takes a time and a *format* and returns a date object that you can use for further processing. The format uses `%x` characters to represent various bits and pieces of dates and times. The manpage for [date](http://man.cx/date) usually contains the `%x` formats and what they represent. Once I get the date, I use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to format the date.

I put all of this into a hash and then push a ***reference*** to that hash into an array containing all of data you're interested in. Note that backslash in front of `%data` in the `push` statement. That's very important, or I'm simply pushing six fields into my `@lines. If you haven't used Perl references before, you should read the [tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). References allow you to create complex data structures.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;

my @lines;
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    next if $line !~ /^\d/;         # Skip first line
    my ( $date, $time, $server, $application ) = split /\s+/, $line;
    next if $application =~ /\W+/;
    my $time_format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M";
    my $date_obj = Time::Piece->strptime( "$date $time", $time_format)
        or die qq(Invalid datetime format "$date $time".);
    my $formatted_date = sprintf "%02d-%s-%04d %02d:%02d",
        $date_obj->mday, $date_obj->month, $date_obj->year,
        $date_obj->hour, $date_obj->min;
    my %data = ( 
        date   => $formatted_date, 
        app    => $application, 
        server => $server, 
    );
    push @lines, \%data;
}
say Dumper \@lines;
__DATA__
Date                 Server        application
01/02/2013 00:00     abc123        perl_module_1
01/02/2013 00:00     abc123        oracle_patch_201
03/05/2014 00:00     abc123        Microsoft()_pa.1.tch_71 (2)
04/04/2015 00:00     xyz1          oracle_patch_201
02/12/2015 00:00     xyz1          Cygwin_app
03/11/2013 00:00     lpr567        perl_module_1
```

This will print out:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'server' => 'abc123',
            'time' => '02-Jan-2013 00:00',
            'app' => 'perl_module_1'
          },
          {
            'app' => 'oracle_patch_201',
            'server' => 'abc123',
            'time' => '02-Jan-2013 00:00'
          },
          {
            'app' => 'oracle_patch_201',
            'server' => 'xyz1',
            'time' => '04-Apr-2015 00:00'
          },
          {
            'app' => 'Cygwin_app',
            'server' => 'xyz1',
            'time' => '12-Feb-2015 00:00'
          },
          {
            'server' => 'lpr567',
            'time' => '11-Mar-2013 00:00',
            'app' => 'perl_module_1'
          }
        ];
```

From here, you should be able to figure out how to get the output you desire.